# Interpolation in excel with uneven amount of data

Tags: excel, matlab, excel-formula, interpolation

I have a base data set which includes elevation and dept. then I have my own data set that has depth and corresponding temperature value for this depth. there is more data points in the measured data. I need to calculate the true vertical depth of this MD_data.

I am trying to interpolate the  measured depth to the elevation but cannot figure it out either with excel or matlab.

Could anyone help.

For example:

Base data:

```
Elevation MD_1
5.13    0
2.9     3
0.68    6
```

and then my own data:

```
MD_data temp
0.71    11.01
0.76    11.0086
0.81    10.9663
0.86    10.9318
0.91    10.9182
0.96    10.8929
1.01    10.8746
1.06    10.8506
1.11    10.8495
1.16    10.8333
1.21    10.8162
1.26    10.8273
1.31    10.8178
1.36    10.7959
1.41    10.8046
1.46    10.7864
1.51    10.7972
1.56    10.7994
1.61    10.7878
1.66    10.7709
1.71    10.7745
1.76    10.7559
1.81    10.7559
1.86    10.751
1.91    10.7483
1.96    10.7508
2.01    10.7433
2.06    10.7393
2.11    10.7199
2.16    10.7167
2.21    10.7288
2.26    10.7073
2.31    10.6963
2.36    10.7073
2.41    10.7071
2.46    10.6846
2.51    10.6646
2.55    10.6653
2.6     10.6644
2.65    10.6406
2.7     10.6254
2.75    10.6189
2.8     10.6079
2.85    10.6008
2.9     10.5731
2.95    10.5565
3       10.5586
3.05    10.5456
3.1     10.5236
3.15    10.5166
3.2     10.4955
3.25    10.4893
3.3     10.4689
3.35    10.425
3.4     10.4066
3.45    10.426
3.5     10.368
3.55    10.3387
3.6     10.3343
3.65    10.3008
3.7     10.2471
3.75    10.2524
3.8     10.2117
3.85    10.1843
3.9     10.1568
3.95    10.1285
4       10.125
4.05    10.0546
4.1     10.0416
4.15    10.0153
4.2     9.99575
4.25    9.94704
4.3     9.9299
4.35    9.89131
4.4     9.8462
4.45    9.83795
4.5     9.76133
4.55    9.73264
4.6     9.68054
4.65    9.65384
4.7     9.6216
4.75    9.61552
4.8     9.52464
4.84    9.52095
4.89    9.47829
4.94    9.44347
4.99    9.41413
5.04    9.36617
5.09    9.33437
5.14    9.28475
5.19    9.25456
5.24    9.23113
5.29    9.19137
5.34    9.14046
5.39    9.11016
5.44    9.07665
5.49    9.04492
5.54    8.97973
5.59    8.94247
5.64    8.90707
5.69    8.85949
5.74    8.81783
5.79    8.77764
5.84    8.73316
5.89    8.69131
5.94    8.64269
5.99    8.62218
6.04    8.57532
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation is fairly easy in Matlab.  Check out interp1(): https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

If you provide the 3-row data as x and v (column 2 and column 1 respectively), and the first column n-row as xq you'll get back the corresponding elevations for your n-row data.

Keep in mind that you should have some idea of how you want to interpolate.  Linear interpolation vs. cubic interpolation vs. others will produce different results.  That link will have some documentation as to which method does what.